# Connecting/configuring two switches to a router?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, packet-tracer

I'm a first year network engineering student and just got into Cisco today, so please bear with me..

I'm trying to setup two switches to connect to each other via a router

> .
>   [image: like this]

but I can't seem to make devices from the A switch to connect to devices from the B switch. I tried searchinig on Youtube and found one that works but it uses a DHCP server to assign IPs to the connected devices like this..

> .
>   [image: dhcp]

Is there a way to connect devices from the A switch to B switch via a router without DHCP server ? If yes, can you help me configure it? I have uploaded the .pkt file if needed

Comment: host config, homework are off-topic here. this stack is for people working in a professional environmet. this sort of Q can go on the Super User stack.

Comment: it's not actually a homework i was just trying new things to get ahead for the next material.. but sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need DHCP to make them talk to each other.

First make sure you can ping the default gateway (it's the LAN facing interface of the router Fa0/0 and Fa0/1).

Check the IP addressing. The router has two directly attached networks. To make it work only proper IP addressing is required. Did you configure VLAN's ?

Comment: It worked ! I was entering the interface's IPs as dns server on the nodes and left the gateway empty.. after filling the gateway with the interface ip it worked wonderfully, thanks !

Comment: can you explain the difference between the two? teacher told us to use interface IP as dns server on the end devices but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Just configure static IPs on your terminals, with good netmasks / subnets, and then:

- for the switch A sub-network, give Router0.Fa0/0 adress as default gateway;
- and for the switch B sub-network, give Router0.Fa0/1 adress ad default gateway.

And then, on your router, add the two sub-netorks on your routing table.

Comment: There's no need to edit the routing table. Both networks are directly reachable. The router has all it needs to route between both networks (assuming he configured the addressing properly).